# How to vibrate mobile while scrolling android-wheel?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to **vibrate mobile & play sound** for each item change, when user scroll [**android-wheel**](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/).

I've seen this in the default time-picker of iPhone. When we scroll time in the time-picker, it plays ticking sound.

Is it possible? If yest then how ?

Kindly edit the question, If it is not asked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import android.os.Vibrator;




ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                    v.vibrate(500);}
        });
```

Don't forget to include permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: `onScrollStateChanged` called only when user start/stop scrolling... not for each item. :(

Comment: how you differentiate single item scroll in listview??

Comment: I've corrected my question, kindly review it again...!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

**Step-1** add in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**Step-2** in `onCreate()` method

```
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_sound);
```

**Step-2** set `setOnScrollListener` on `ListView`:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                 v.vibrate(500);
                           mp.start();
                 Log.i("a", "scrolling...");
        }
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                Log.i("a", "scrolling stoped...");                  

        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've tried the above code, it vibrates the list for more than the required amount... Means I just starts scrolling and didn't even scrolled one item... but mobile vibrates for more than 10 times... I've checked the log, the method is called multiple times...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late to answer but may be this will help some other.

what you need to do is to add below code inside the  **onBindViewHolder**   of the Adapter class.

```
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) holder.itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    // Vibrate for 20 milliseconds
    v.vibrate(20);
```

This will vibrate your device each time an item is binded with the recyclerView.

Comment: Won't this make the device vibrate a bunch of times when the list is initialised depending on the size of the items,